# Android - Play Store search by title

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an application to the Play Store. The problem is that the title of my app is XXX YYY, but when I type XXX YYY in there is no app in the search list/index, but if I type XXXYYY I can find my application.

Does anyone have a similar problem or a suggestion?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, been almost 2 weeks now... I've noticed if i search my app name surrounded by quotes i can find it eg "my app name" works fine... Have you perhaps found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

It can take a number of days for the search indexes in the play store to refresh, especially if it not an English speaking play store (USA, UK, etc). If you are able to see your application in the store then it is working correctly, you just need to wait for Google to properly index your application.

Something that would be worth checking is your applications name in your manifest file; it is possible that you have named it without the space. Google will use that value (plus the description/comments/etc) to build up the search index.